# Toggle list to display based on selected radio button

Tags: vue.js, pug, toggle

I have a piece of code that asks the user where they want to display their ad. The options are and i have them as radio buttons:

- All states
- select states
- all states except the following...

I want the lists of states to appear to the user when they either select 'select states' or 'all states except the following'.

This is what i tried but wasn't able to get it working:

```
showStates: boolean = false;


.form-check
input.form-check-input(type="radio")  
label All States  

.form-check
input.form-check-input(type="radio" @click='showStates  = !showStates')   
label all states except except:  

.form-check
input.form-check-input(type="radio" @click='showStatus = !showStates')  
 label selected states:
```

view page

```
(div to show states)
.collapse.container(v-show='showStates')

Select states.
 .col-6(v-for='location in locationList')
.form-check
input.form-check-input(type='checkbox')
label.form-check-label {{location.name}}
```

how can i get this so the states div only show when i click on the two radio buttons?

Comment: Add Whatever you've done to achieve it

Comment: @varit05 i did.. i created a variable boolean set it to false by default and added click on the buttons to toggle boolean and used v-show to try to display the div...as i have above but it is not working

Comment: showStatus changes in vue devtools? I think you should use `@input` or `@change` not `@click`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radio buttons only emit change events.  Try using `@change` instead of `@click`.